# Rotate image by 90°

Tags: javascript, titanium

I want to build a titanium app which rotates pictures by 90 degrees. My view shows the imageView and the button I want to use to rotate the button. But I always get 'undefined' errors. See my code and logs below:

```
var image;
var imageSet = false;

var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "savedChallengeImage.jpeg");
if(file) {
    $.picture.setImage(file);
    image = file;
    imageSet = true;
}

function rotate() {
    if (imageSet) {
        var t = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix(); 
        var spin = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
        t = t.rotate(90);
        spin.transform = t;
        file.animate(spin);
    } 
}
```

EDIT: I've changed the file object to an image object but it behaves in the same way. Am I getting the image object correctly?

```
image = $.picture.getImage();
image.animate(spin);
```

And my log:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at :0";
[ERROR] :      line = 17;
[ERROR] :      message = "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'file.animate(spin)')";
[ERROR] :      name = TypeError;
[ERROR] :      sourceId = 319168864;
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/rellerkmann/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/97B059B3-D010-402B-834F-E2647DC8BBC9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BB7A6057-D27E-4AB3-92AB-051BE30087BE/RegApp.app/alloy/controllers/challengePicturePage.js";
[ERROR] :  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the File object does not have an animate method. You would have to use the ImageView object.

[File](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File)

[ImageView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView)

You can also look here for reference:
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/84171/rotate-an-image-around-its-center

Comment: This change did not improve things. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: When you use getImage() you are returned a File object again. Have you tried $.picture.animate?